# Downcast union cases without warning errors

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

How can I make compiler ignore some downcast pattern matching warnings (FS0025) but must capture other FS0025 warnings in the same file?

For example, the first pattern match `(Student studentName) = john` would never throw an error so I want the compiler to remove an unnecessary warning.

```
type Job = Student of string | Teacher of string

let john = Student "John"

(* FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example,
the value 'Teacher _' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s). *)
let (Student studentName) = john
let (Teacher teacherName) = john // runtime error
```

**I tried:**

```
#nowarn "25"
let (Student studentName) = john
#warn "25"
let (Teacher teacherName) = john
```

But it doesn't show any warning error for `let (Teacher teacherName) = john`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a GADT to record in the type the constructor that was used you can write something like this (OCaml syntax, I don't have F# installed):

```
type student
type teacher

type _ job =
  | Student : string -> student job
  | Teacher : string -> teacher job

let john = Student "John"
```

Your first pattern-matching is then accepted without emitting a warning (it is total: there is only one constructor for a value of type `student job`):

```
let (Student studentName) = john
```

Whilst the second one is rejected at *type-checking time* because `student` and `teacher` are not equal:

```
let (Teacher teacherName) = john
```

You can write functions ranging over all `job`s by writing functions from `'a job`.

Comment: This is very nice solution, sadly F# doesn't support GADT.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, both cases have the same data, a single name string, so you could pattern match to get the name:

```
let name = match john with Student n | Teacher n -> n
```

You could add this as a member on the type if you're going to do it many times:

```
type Job =
    | Student of string
    | Teacher of string
    member this.Name = match this with Student n | Teacher n -> n

let john = Student "John"
let name = john.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Without access to GADTs, you have to add a bit of extra boilerplate in the form of an additional wrapper type:

```
type Student = Student of string 
type Teacher = Teacher of string

type Job = StudentJob of Student | TeacherJob of Teacher

let john = Student "John"

let (Student studentName) = john // no warning
let (Teacher teacherName) = john // compile error
```